# How do I create a collapsible element with just CSS using input and labels?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to collapse an element to only be revealed when the label of a hidden input is clicked. I want the `<section>` to change from `display: none` to `display: block` when the label is clicked.

I have the following styles and html.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  content: "\00a0+"; 
}

section.site_navigation {
  background-color: #eed;
  display: none;
}

input#menu_collapse {
  display: none;
}

label[for=menu_collapse] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #027;
  color: #ffe;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[checked]#menu_collapse + label[for=menu_collapse] + section.site_navigation {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse">
<label for="menu_collapse">Menu</label>
<section class="site_navigation">
  <p>A lot of stuff</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- the section is supposed to appear when the damned label is clicked on -->
```

Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/LadyAleena/pen/BaNezbp?editors=1100) to a live version.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _“How do I create a collapsible element with just CSS using input and labels?”_ - if you give anything about accessibility, in even the slighest way, then you simply _don’t_. Accessibility-wise, these “pure HTML and CSS“ solutions are almost always terrible.

Comment: @CBroe, the reason I stay away from javascript is that I do not know it. If I need javascript for something, I end being a vagabond going from place to place looking for someone to write the script for me. I have tried over and over again to learn it, but its structure is too chaotic for me. I found Perl easier to learn. So, I go around the web looking at CSS for things, and try them. This is one time I could not get some CSS to work as expected and was lost as to why.

Comment: Fair enough; I just mentioned it because a lot of people act like these “pure CSS solutions” were the better way to go in general, because they don’t rely on JS being activated in the browser (which is true, of course - but since this is rather rare in reality, a fallback that does show everything right from the start, usually is enough to handle the few cases where that might actually apply.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.
Changing this selector

```
input[checked]#menu_collapse
```

to

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked#menu_collapse
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  content: "\00a0+";
}

section.site_navigation {
  background-color: #eed;
  display: none;
}

input#menu_collapse {
  display: none;
}

label[for="menu_collapse"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #027;
  color: #ffe;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked#menu_collapse
  + label[for="menu_collapse"]
  + section.site_navigation {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse">
<label for="menu_collapse">Menu</label>
<section class="site_navigation">
  <p>A lot of stuff</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<!-- the section is supposed to appear when the damned label is clicked on -->
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me where I went wrong. I did not have the pseudo element :checked as part of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a combination of native HTML5 **details** and **summary** tags?

If you use the following structure, your elements will be both collapsable and semantically meaningful for browsers/crawlers. You can style all these elements like you'd normally do with any other HTML tag. [Browser support is also very good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=details).

```html
<details>
  <summary>Menu</summary>
  <p>A lot of stuff</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

[To find out more about implementation and customisation of the tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Customizing_the_disclosure_widget).

Comment: I was thinking about using the details/summary combination, but I was reading some manuals of style elsewhere. Those manuals suggested that this solution to hide/show just anything is not semantic. So, the use in this case would be inappropriate. Thank you for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  content: "\00a0+"; 
}

section.site_navigation {
  background-color: #eed;
  display: none;
}

input#menu_collapse {
  display: none;
}

label[for=menu_collapse] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #027;
  color: #ffe;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[checked]#menu_collapse + label[for=menu_collapse] + section.site_navigation {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <label for="menu_collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">MENU</label>
<section id="demo" class="collapse">
  <p>A lot of stuff</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
  </ul>
</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you use javascript? I can not see the difference between your styles and my styles. I do not want to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this I think work for you

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse" >
<label for="menu_collapse" > menu</label>
<section class="site_navigation">
  <p>A lot of stuff</p>
   <ul>
     <li>Page 1</li>
     <li>Page 2</li>
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Css code

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

label[for="menu_collapse"] {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;

  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;
}

label[for="menu_collapse"]:hover {
  color: #7C5A0B;
}

label[for="menu_collapse"]::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);

  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked  {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.site_navigation {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for="menu_collapse"] + .site_navigation {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label[for="menu_collapse"] {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

live version [here](https://codepen.io/Naqvi/pen/WNvBoOq?editors=1100&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=bb00a322e648bd22802b813c84d352483377188f-1586275179-0-AdmE4Fsxo4OFD-_rmOLMGZbX-yKDgdJIKBn6Bl22MFUq-rAmJFtIZ0yKBD1YdEnO3hm4hRNL0NBlJD4ySPi4At7T1Orq5tqfQqOqFS3bCVb2ML-wlHx8XwzocFAlfbseo4frUch_zX3i0lmvYy8xM223GdE-P-hJ1g9cUTXlTDXppLZwTgraa2sCu3GGxv038Kjj2rfkJTbz8SwITup0rJOoS-0GKKYAa-tPr5tiy5x1jXw1Z0OgsQsn9KYCrMgOzUUgX_-fdjaWySNMbmtY7OZOITtKrcS3RS7ggdaU44KWXZSiN7ZF1RiUnGUsUUKYNDPdGa-rdIuW5kTnFtz6s7pA98fMR-2BRGx1NorTt_BooVP9NjbyrRa07Nnd6-M08g)

Comment: The problem with your solution was that you did not use the elements and classes in my code. I would have to strip it to just the code that I have. This answer looks very similar to what I found during a web search on this subject. (https://alligator.io/css/collapsible/) Now if it had just the elements and classes in my original example, that would be great.

Comment: Yeah! I think you have not a problem for custom css so I  add some amazing transitions.Now I  updated my code according to your html file.
I think now 
code will be helpfull for you.if you have any more querys feel free to asked from me your question.I always avaiable for helping peoples